# Area of parallelogram by projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given $\{x,y\}$ linearly independent, with $\alpha$ is an angle between them. There is parallelogram spanned by $\{x,y\}$. The area of parallelogram is
$$Area = \Vert x \Vert \left(\Vert y \Vert \sin\alpha\right).$$
From above formula, $\Vert x \Vert$ is the base and $\Vert y\Vert \sin\alpha$ is the height.

On the other hand, we know $proj_x(y)$. The height of parallelogram can be written as $y - proj_x(y)$. So geometrically we can write
$$Area = \Vert x \Vert \Vert y - proj_x(y)\Vert.$$

In both cases, I want to proof that
$$\Vert y \Vert \sin \alpha = \Vert y - proj_x(y)\Vert$$
analytically.

Comment: I’m confused about what is known and what isn’t.  The second term in the product is the height in both cases. Draw the right triangle giving  $y$ as the sum of the projection and the remainder.

Comment: Actually I'm doubt that
$\Vert y \Vert \sin \alpha = \Vert y - proj_x(y) \Vert.$

How can I proof the equality analytically?

Comment: Put the angle $\alpha$ in the right triangle I just told you to draw.

Comment: I have already drawn the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the triangle Ted Shifrin wants you to draw. The equation you are trying to prove is simply the definition of $\sin \alpha$ applied to this diagram:

[image]

Comment: To be thorough, you also need to examine the case when $\alpha > \frac \pi 2$, where $\alpha$ is an external angle to the triangle. But then the corresponding internal angle is $\pi - \alpha$, and $\sin (\pi - \alpha) = \sin \alpha$ so the result still holds.